# Function says the argument is missing but I've put it in the function, why does it say it's missing?

Tags: r, function, arguments

This is probably a very simple question and I'm missing something but I have a function:

Traffic<-function(lights,cars,roads,accidents)

In this function I only use the cars argument, lights, roads and accidents aren't used but are still needed as arguments for other parts of the code I will do later on.
When I try to run my function it says that 'cars' is missing with no default value, but it's there. The function works when cars is the first argument but I need the arguments in the order I've given.

Is there a way to stop it from saying the argument is missing when it's there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't supplied default values for `cars` (or the other arguments), so you need to supply values when you call the function.  If they aren't used in the current version of your function, the values you supply can be anything: `NA`, `list()` and `NULL` are obvious options.

```
x <- Traffic(NA, myCars, NA, NA)
```

Alternatively, you can supply default values in the function definition, eg

```
Traffic <- function(lights=NA, cars, roads=NA, accidents=NA)
```

and then call it with

```
x <- Traffic(cars=myCars)
```

If you just call your function with

```
x <- Traffic(myCars)
```

Then the object `myCars` is associated with the `lights` argument, not `cars`.